# Zend_Db PDO exception arises with a mySQL View?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

After updating from `Zend 1.12.1` to `1.12.3` and turning `x_debug on` and making `OLD_PASSWORD` the `default`.

I rerun a program that used to run and seamlessly and it now has a fatal `PDOException`, detailed below:

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'place_fcb.userid' in 'group statement'
```

Actual SQl Query:

```
SELECT `C`.* 
FROM (SELECT `place_fcb`.* FROM `place_fcb`) 
AS `C` 
WHERE (place_type_id != '176') 
GROUP BY place_fcb.userid
HAVING (place_fcb.pda >= '2009-12-21') 
AND (place_fcb.pda <= '2010-01-20')
```

Zend_Db_table_Abstract:

```
 public function getPlacefcb($start_date = '', $end_date = '', $r_id = '')
    {
        $sub_sql = $this->select()->from('place_fcb');

        $select = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('C' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$sub_sql.')')))
            ->where("place_type_id != '176'")
            ->group('place_fcb.userid');

        if($start_date != '')
            $select->having('`place_fcb`.`pda` >= ?', $start_date);

        if($end_date != '')
            $select->having('`place_fcb`.`pda` <= ?', $end_date);

        if($region_id != '')
            $select->having('`place_fcb`.`r_id` = ?', $r_id);

        return $rowset = $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
```

MySQL of place_fcb:

place_fcb is a VIEW not a table. It has the following relevant fields

```
place_id
r_id
place_type_id
pda
userid
```

I can remove the exception and return the same results by changing the SQl statement to:

```
    SELECT `C`.* 
    FROM (SELECT `place_fcb`.* FROM `place_fcb`) 
    AS `C` 
    WHERE (place_type_id != '176') 
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING (pda >= '2009-12-21') 
    AND (pda <= '2010-01-20')
```

ie. removing all the table suffixes...

but how will I fix it with Zend? and why is it going wrong all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your query use the subquery:

```
->from(array('C' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$sub_sql.')')))
```

Instead of simply:

```
->from('place_fcb')
```

With the former, there is no `place_fcb` table in the outer query; hence so-qualified references fail (and always would, so I can't see how it used to work for you prior to this upgrade).

If you insist on keeping the subquery, you could rename the subquery's alias from `'C'` to `'place_fcb'`, although that is likely to cause confusion in the long term; better to rename the qualified references from `'place_fcb'` to `'C'`.

Comment: You are quite correct and on the production version it used:         
            `->from(array('place_fcb' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$sub_sql.')')))` .....Would it be best practise to change this to simply `->from(place_fcb)`

Comment: @StevieG: So long as the subquery remains unchanged, I would indeed remove it entirely and replace like that.